# Combine: updating Values Code (with Case statement, Inner Join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

everyone

I've the following codes:

```
update New_Clients_Report set
YTD_Jan13 = (case   when StatementID>='01.01.2013' then 'New from Jan-13'
                    else 'Repead' end)
    from New_Clients_Report so inner join MonthSales_NC nc
on so.ClientID=nc.NewClientID and nc.NewClientDate='01.01.2013'

update New_Clients_Report set
YTD_Jan13 = (case   when StatementID>='02.01.2013' then 'New from Feb-13'
                    else 'Repead' end)
    from New_Clients_Report so inner join MonthSales_NC nc
on so.ClientID=nc.NewClientID and nc.NewClientDate='02.01.2013'

update New_Clients_Report set
YTD_Jan13 = (case   when StatementID>='03.01.2013' then 'New from Mar-13'
                    else 'Repead' end)
    from New_Clients_Report so inner join MonthSales_NC nc
on so.ClientID=nc.NewClientID and nc.NewClientDate='03.01.2013'
```

And So on untill 05.01.2014

Code works well, if I'm running separately.

add info:
1)"New from Jan-14" for those clients who are working with us from January, 2014;
2)"New from Feb-14" for those clients who are working with us from February, 2014;
3)"New from Mar-14" for those clients who are working with us from March, 2014

I want to combining these code into one
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering "New from Jan-14" for those clients who are working from January, 2014 and also that their StatementID is greater than January, 2014 then you can write the update statement as:

```
update New_Clients_Report set
YTD_Jan13 = (case   when StatementID>=NewClientDate then 'New from ' 
             + REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), NewClientDate, 6), 6), ' ', '-')
             else 'Repead' end)
from New_Clients_Report so inner join MonthSales_NC nc
on so.ClientID=nc.NewClientID 
--and nc.NewClientDate='01.01.2013'
```

Check [Demo here.](http://rextester.com/SFEPQ42319)